# How to interact with shapes in Pixijs?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am trying to get the id of the shape my mouse is currently hovering over.

my shapes are in a container

```
// creating the layers
gridLayer = new PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer ();
gridLayer.setInteractive(true);
stage.addChild(gridLayer);
```

and i am creating each shape like this;

```
function drawHexagon(x,y, size, gap,scale, color, iterI, iterJ, type) {
    var shape = new PIXI.Graphics();
    // set a fill and line style
    shape.beginFill(color);
    shape.lineStyle(1, 0xa0a0a0, 1);
    size = size-gap;

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        angle = 2 * Math.PI / 6 * (i + 0.5);
        var x_i = x + size * Math.cos(angle);
        var y_i = y + size * Math.sin(angle);


        if (i === 0) { 
            shape.moveTo(x_i, scale *y_i) 
        }
        else {
            shape.lineTo(x_i, scale * y_i)
        }
    };

    shape.endFill();

    // calculate and save the axial coordinates
    var cX = iterJ - (iterI - (iterI&1)) / 2;
    var cZ = iterI;
    var cY = -1*(cX+cZ);

    shape.hexId = cX + "x" + cY + "y" + cZ + "z";
    shape.hexPosX = x;
    shape.hexPosY = y;

    shape.setInteractive(true);
    shape.mouseover = function(mouseData){
       console.log("MOUSE OVER " + shape.hexId);
    }
    shape.click = function(mouseData){
       console.log("MOUSE CLICK " + shape.hexId);
    }
    gridLayer.addChild(shape);
}
```

However, clicking on any shape or hovering over it is not showing me anything in the console. what am i doing wrong?

i have tried both

```
shape.setInteractive(true)
```

and

```
shape.interactive = true
```

but neither seems to work for me.

EDIT: i have added a jsfiddle. it doesnt works (i dont know how to link things in jsfiddle) but you can see my entire code in there.
http://jsfiddle.net/9aqHz/1/

Comment: Did you make your stage interactive by passing true to the 2nd param of the Stage constructor? e.g. new PIXI.Stage(0x000000, true)

Comment: yes. but strangely i am still not getting the console.log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a PIXI.Graphics object to be interactive you need to set a hitArea shape (it can be a Rectangle, Circle or a Polygon):

```
shape.hitArea = new PIXI.Polygon([
   new PIXI.Point(/* first point */),
   new PIXI.Point(/* second point */),
   new PIXI.Point(/* third point */),
   new PIXI.Point(/* fourth point */),
   new PIXI.Point(/* fifth point */)
]);
```

Another approach would be to generate a texture from the shape and use a Sprite, but the hit area would be the entire rectangular bounds of the hexagon:

```
var texture = shape.generateTexture();
var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
sprite.setInteractive(true);
sprite.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
```

[Fiddle with this applied to your example](http://jsfiddle.net/imcg/LP2j8/)

Comment: Thank you.
the thing which mainly confused me was this text in the pixi blog, where the author says :
"The only other thing worth mentioning is that you can also set a hitArea for a displayObject. The hitArea defines a rectangle that will be used for touch and mouse detection for that displayObject.
If your display object contains tonnes of children then using a hitArea could also be a neat way of optimising your code as it means that touch/mouse detection becomes a lot simpler for the interaction manager!"
which made me think that hitboxes are optional and are used mainly for optimization.

Comment: Yes it's not intuitive at all, in contrast to most of PIXI's features which are super easy to get used to. The polygon hitArea option is pretty cool though!

Answer (score 2):

@imcg I updated your code so it workes with Pixi 3.0.8

```
- sprite.setInteractive(true);
+ shape.interactive = true;
+ shape.buttonMode = true;

- sprite.setInteractive(true)
+ sprite.interactive = true;
+ sprite.buttonMode = true;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LP2j8/56/

Answer (score 0):

I will add a bit of info for anyone who is in the same boat i was in;

When you define a shape as a geom, you have to explicitly state a hitarea.

So adding the following code makes it work;

```
shape.hitArea = new PIXI.Polygon(vertices);
shape.interactive = true;

shape.click = function(mouseData){
   console.log("MOUSE CLICK " + shape.hexId);
}
```

But, when you define a shape as a sprite/texture, you dont need to do this.
in cases of sprites, just setting `shape.interactive = true` for the sprite is sufficient. You dont need to set the interactive property for the parent object or the stage.

Comment: In case you want to reuse vertices of a Graphics-object as hitArea, you can use:

myObject.hitArea = myObject.currentPath.shape;